# Postgresql ST_Point problem (Can't see point symbol on map)

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, postgresql, arcgis-10.4, st-geometry

i am using Arcgis for Server and Arcgis Portal webmaps with Postgresql db.
Created a Feature Class with ArcCatalog and shared as Feature Service, so i am trying to add data to this Feature Class with a Sql Query. (Geometry column name "shape")

**i made success adding data with these queries;**

```
INSERT INTO sde.data_table (objectid, name, globalid, shape)
VALUES (21,'dataname',sde.next_globalid(),sde.ST_Geometry('point (622000 4122000)', 32635)
);
```

**or**

```
INSERT INTO sde.data_table (objectid, name, globalid, shape)
VALUES (21,'dataname',sde.next_globalid(),sde.ST_Geometry('point (622000 4122000)', 32635)
);
```

**or**

```
INSERT INTO sde.data_table (objectid, name, globalid, shape)
VALUES (sde.next_rowid('sde', 'data_table'),'dataname',sde.next_globalid(),sde.ST_Geometry('point (622000 4122000)', 32635)
);
```

My problem is; I can **see** data with Arcmap's and Webmap created with Portal Attribute Table, but i cannot see point symbol on the map, it is there but no symbol, also i cannot identify with a mouse click. Just like a hidden object.

---

PostgreSQL 9.4.5 /
Arcmap 10.4 /
Arcgis For Server /
Arcgis Portal

Comment: Hi. my problem solved. I choose the right Srid then symbols showed on the web map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding the point without assigning an OBJECTID value? The OBJECTID value is supposed to be system maintained, hence you trying to insert that value could be your problem.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/object-id.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_CCCEC3DEBCB243BDAA0EB74DD8D28355

Comment: i tried widhout objectid;
 result:
 ERROR:null value in column "objectid" violates not-null constraint